# HTML2pdf Css not supporting

Tags: php, css, pdf

I have used a `html2pdf` file for generating pdf.But it does not support css at all. Please let me know what is the issue.

1) Downloaded file from 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/?source=typ_redirect

2) placed in a folder and used below code to generate pdf (working fine)

```
require("html2fpdf.php");  
$buffer = "<div>
<h1>Hello Friends</h1><br>
<p>This is a sample code</p>
</div>";
$pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Legal'); 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->WriteHTML($buffer); 
$pdf->Output('my.pdf', 'D');
```

but when i used css in this then generated pdf is not opened

```
require("html2fpdf.php");  
$buffer = "<div style='width:950px;'>
<h1>Hello Friends</h1><br>
<p style='font-size:10'>This is a sample code</p>
</div>";
$pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Legal'); 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->WriteHTML($buffer); 
$pdf->Output('my.pdf', 'D');
```

My php version is `PHP Version 5.3.8`.

I am bowed  to use HTML2PDF. So please answer if you know(I have used same with TCPDF and thats working fine but i need to implement same in HTML2PDF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did two tests and CSS is working well except for the size of the div.

PHP Version : 5.6.30

**Test 1**

```
<?php
require("html2fpdf.php");
$buffer = "
<h1>Hello Friends</h1><br>
<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 18pt; color: #FF0000; font-family: Times'>Hello there! I am red!<br></span>
<br>
<p style='font-size:10'>This is a sample code</p>
<p style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'>This is a sample code</p>
<span style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'>This is a sample code</p>
<span style='font-weight: italic; font-size: 10pt; color: #00FF00;'>I am a pdf ! Please accept my answer!</span>
";
$pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Legal');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML($buffer);
$pdf->Output('my.pdf', 'D');

 ?>
```

**Result** 
[image: result]
**Test 2**

```
<?php
require("html2fpdf.php");
$buffer = "<div style='width:950px;'>
<h1>Hello Friends</h1><br>
<span style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 18pt; color: #FF0000; font-family: Times'>Hello there! I am red!<br></span>
<br>
<p style='font-size:10'>This is a sample code</p>
<p style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'>This is a sample code</p>
<span style='font-size:10px; color:blue;'>This is a sample code</p>
<span style='font-weight: italic; font-size: 10pt; color: #00FF00;'>I am a pdf ! Please accept my answer!</span></div>
";
$pdf = new HTML2FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Legal');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML($buffer);
$pdf->Output('my.pdf', 'D');

 ?>
```

**Result**

[image: result2]

Answer (score 0):

**Got Your Issue :** Just Remove `<div></div>` from your code

Instead of using :

```
$buffer = "<div>
<h1>Hello Friends</h1><br>
<p>This is a sample code</p>
</div>";
```

Use :

```
$buffer = "<h1>Hello Friends</h1><br>
<p>This is a sample code</p>";
```

Comment: no thats not the issue. My issue is that css not supporting in html

Comment: CSS is working fine for me with PHP 5.6.30. Can you change your PHP version ?

Comment: you can comment on Question instead of Answer